# mysql update in a while loop only updating the last result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to update MySQL table with results extracted from another table using a while loop but its only updating the last result set.

here is the code

```
$qa=$db->query("SELECT *, (acq_subudget.RemBal-order_items.total_cost) AS rama FROM order_items, acq_subudget WHERE invoice_num='$ordnumber_update' AND acq_subudget.id=order_items.disc");


while($qa_data=$qa->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
set_time_limit(0);
$account_remaining=$qa_data['rama'];
$account_name=$qa_data['acq_subudget.disc'];
$account_id=$qa_data['id'];
$qa_update=$db->exec("UPDATE `acq_subudget` SET RemBal='$account_remaining' WHERE id='$account_id'");
}
```

i am using pdo

Comment: use $qa_data[{table_name}.id], my bet is that the id you are fetching is taken from the last table.

Comment: or, did you mean $qa_data['account_id']; ??

Comment: By any chance do both order_items and acq_subudget have columns called id?

Answer (score 0):

you are using fetch instead of fetchAll, fetch only gets the next row from the result set

Comment: Fetch keeps fetching subsequent rows until it returns NULL when it hits the end of the result set. Fetch all returns the entire resultset at once. Often using fetch is considered the better option because the database server can stream the results to the client as it processes them concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, you can probably do this in a single statement without needing a loop:-

```
UPDATE acq_subudget
INNER JOIN order_items
ON acq_subudget.id = order_items.disc
SET acq_subudget.RemBal = acq_subudget.RemBal-order_items.total_cost
WHERE acq_subudget.invoice_num='$ordnumber_update'
```